# Como mover un picture box de un lugar a otro con hilos

Tags: c#, hilos, picturebox

Quiero mover un picture box de un lugar a otro.

Intente con:

Creo un picture box de manera manual para poder tener varios picture box moviéndose cada que pulse el botón.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox nuevo = new PictureBox();
        nuevo.Location = new Point(X, 27);
        nuevo.Visible = true;
        nuevo.Size = new Size(46, 50);
        nuevo.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        nuevo.BackColor = Color.Red;
        Controls.Add(nuevo);

        ThreadStart gen = new ThreadStart(()=> Mover_Creado(nuevo));
        hilo = new Thread(gen);
        hilo.Start();
    }
```

En este método voy cambiando el valor de X para mover la posición del picture box

```
        public void Mover_Creado(PictureBox nuevo)
    {
        int X = 247;
        while (X <= 941 || X > 941)
        {
            if (X <= 941)
            {
                X += 2;
                PermitirMover_creado(X, nuevo);
            }
            else
            {
                X = 247;
                PermitirMover_creado(X, nuevo);
            }
        }
    }
```

En este método hago un invoke de ser requerido y muevo el picture box

```
        public void PermitirMover_creado(int X,PictureBox nuevo)
    {
        if (nuevo.InvokeRequired)
        {
            Delegado del = new Delegado(PermitirMover_creado(X,nuevo));
            nuevo.Invoke(del, new object[] { X,nuevo });
        }
        else
            nuevo.Location = new Point(X, 27);
    }
```

Pero me marca "Se espera nombre de método" en:

```
Delegado del = new Delegado(PermitirMover_creado(X,nuevo));
```

Alguien sabe como solucionar ese error?
Ya había logrado que un pcb de la forma se moviera y no me marcaba ningún error pero quiero que hayan varios picture box es por eso que los creo de manera manual en el botón y ahora que el método  "Mover_Creado" recibe como parámetro un pcb me marca error

Comment: Dice "Se espera nombre de método" porque, cito: "Normalmente, un objeto delegado se construye al proporcionar el nombre del método que el delegado encapsulará".  Tendrías que hacerlo así:  Delegado del = new Delegado(PermitirMover_creado);    del(X, nuevo);

Comment: [Utilizar delegados (Guía de programación de C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/using-delegates)

Comment: Gracias por la información ya lo pude solucionar lo que pasaba es que cuando cree mi delegado solo puse como parámetro el valor y no el picture box xd